# Payments outside AppStore SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, app-store

I have submitted an app for review on the AppStore and got declined for:

"Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase - We noticed that your app includes or accesses paid digital content, services, or functionality by means other than in-app purchase, which is not appropriate for the App Store"

There have been many articles saying that Apple now allows payments outside the AppStore however I think my approach is too direct

My approach: users goes to settings, taps "Subscribe" a window opens up, there are two buttons that appear. 1 for the yearly subscription and 1 for the monthly subscription. That link takes the user directly to a Stripe checkout page. How can I bypass this for my app to get verified. I am strongly against Apple Subscriptions.

Comment: There is no way around using StoreKit for digital purchases. Just look at the guideline referenced. You can use a 3rd party for non-digital purchases.

Comment: In that case how does Netflix operate. They run user accounts and subscriptions. If a user was to create a account on my website to unlock all the features to the app would that work?

Comment: As long as you don’t advertise the workaround. You can’t tell the users they can get a better experience by going to the website and subscribing. All of this is in the guidelines.

Comment: You can offer 3rd party payment options on your website, but you're still not allowed to use them directly inside your app (with very few exceptions that probably won't apply to you).